Align items to the right and Navbar drop-down menu not working with Angular 17 and Bootstrap 5.3
I'm developing a web application with Angular 17 and Bootstrap 5.3 and I'm having problems with some features of Bootstrap. I'm following the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/  but I don't know why drop-down menu doesn't work even though I tried possible solutions. Also Right alignment in navbar doesn't work either.All css except these two are working.
My nav.component.html:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

I saved the bootstrap, popper and jquery files with npm install --save.
angular.json:
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ],

And then I put the links in my angular.json file and it didn't work.Except for the two features I mentioned, only other CSS worked.
After, I put these links in my index.html file, but it still did not work.
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Intro</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href= "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BootStrap JS -->
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>

Then, I put the links from the internet in my index.html file and for some reason it worked.
Like that:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Intro</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <!-- BootStrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BootStrap JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>

But I know I shouldn't place it this way and I don't understand why it is like this.

Issue 1: data-* attribute
You are using the data-* attribute which is no longer supported in Bootstrap 5.
Bootstrap 5 Migration

Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own code. For example, we use data-bs-toggle instead of data-toggle.

Make sure that all the data-* attributes are migrated to data-bs-*.
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"
          >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
        >
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a
          class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
          href="#"
          id="navbarDropdown"
          role="button"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input
        class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="Search"
      />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

Issue 2: Dependency on Popper.js
Many Bootstrap 5 components are dependent on the Popper.js. So you have to import the Popper.js (and before import of Bootstrap.js file)
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]

You may work with Bootstrap Bundle also.
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
],

Note that the jQuery is not required to be imported as Bootstrap 5 have removed the dependencies on it.
Demo @ StackBlitz
